# Hide elements that doesn't match user entry

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to filter a group of elements as users key in texts. I want the elements that contain the match to what is being keyed in to move to the top while the others hide simultaneously. My code hides everything instead.

```js
$('input#sort-plate').keyup(function () {
        var value = $('input#sort-plate').val();

        var match = $(".name").filter(function() {
            // don't do this -> return $(this).text().match(new RegExp(value, "i"));
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
        });
        if (match.length) {
            $(".sort-plate").first().before(match.first().parent()).addClass('show-me');
        }
     $(".sort-plate").hide();
    });
```

```css
.name, .center, .phone {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.name {
    width: 55%
}
.center, .phone {
    width: 20%;
}
.sort-by {
    color: red;
}
strong {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plate">
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" id="sort-plate" />
     
      
        </form>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chibueze Okechukwu</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Angelina Jolie</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Michael Jordan</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Deka Junior</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Okorondu</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Angela Jones</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Ikechukwu Adaora</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
    
     <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Okorondu</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Ndolo</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Stones</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="sort-plate">
            <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Johnson</div>
            <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
            <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in one hit using `each`, no need to keep a list of matches as you can handle each one as you go:

```
$('input#sort-plate').keyup(function () {
    var value = $('input#sort-plate').val();
    console.log(value);

    $(".sort-plate").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($(".name", this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            $this.show();
        } else {
            $this.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('input#sort-plate').keyup(function () {
  var value = $('input#sort-plate').val();
  $(".sort-plate").hide();
  var match = $(".name").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
  });
  for(var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
    match.closest('.sort-plate').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.name, .center, .phone {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.name {
    width: 55%
}
.center, .phone {
    width: 20%;
}
.sort-by {
    color: red;
}
strong {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plate">
  <form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="sort-plate" />
  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chibueze Okechukwu</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Angelina Jolie</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Michael Jordan</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Deka Junior</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Okorondu</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Angela Jones</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Ikechukwu Adaora</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Okorondu</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Ndolo</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Stones</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sort-plate">
    <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Johnson</div>
    <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
    <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using `each`, `toggle` and `regex`

```
$('input#sort-plate').keyup(function () {
    var value = $('input#sort-plate').val();    
    $.each($('.sort-plate'),function(){
        $(this).toggle(new RegExp(value, 'i').test($('.name', this).text()));
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g5w1brua/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `div` element to `#plate` as container for `.sort-plate` elements , `.replace()` to remove `"Name"` from `.name` text check , `Array.prototype.sort()` , `.preprendTo()` to prepend selected elements to top of `div`

```js
$('input#sort-plate').on("input", function() {
  var value = this.value;

  var match = $(".sort-plate").filter(function() {
    return new RegExp(value, "i").test($(".name", this).text()
      .replace(/Name/, ""))
  }).get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.textContent
           .replace(/Name/, "")
           .toLowerCase()
           .indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) 
           <                    
           b.textContent
           .replace(/Name/, "")
           .toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) 
           ? 1 : -1
  });
  if (match.length) {

    $(match).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("not-matched")
        .addClass("matched")
        .prependTo($("#plate div:first"))
    })
    $(".sort-plate").not(".matched")
      .removeClass("matched")
      .addClass("not-matched")
  }

});
```

```css
.name,
.center,
.phone {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.name {
  width: 55%
}
append .center,
.phone {
  width: 20%;
}
.sort-by {
  color: red;
}
strong,
.not-matched {
  display: none;
}
.matched {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plate">
  <form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="sort-plate" />


  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chibueze Okechukwu</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Angelina Jolie</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Michael Jordan</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Deka Junior</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Okorondu</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Angela Jones</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Ikechukwu Adaora</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Okorondu</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Ndolo</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Stones</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sort-plate">
      <div class="name"> <strong>Name</strong> Chris Johnson</div>
      <div class="center"> <strong>Department</strong> Act Center</div>
      <div class="phone"> <strong>Ext</strong> 5204</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```